# Dynamic table not displaying array values correct

Tags: php, pdo

I am currently working on a Table class in php. This class creates tables dynamic by only giving values for the column names and an array from the selected data. I am stuck on displaying the values in the correct way I want to. This is how it's looking right now:[current table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQdwD.png) . I thought it could be my the array. In the array all the values are the other way around like this: [array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKOqx.png) . The 2nd is before the 1st id. Here is my Table Class:

```
public function displayTable($columns, $values = 0)
    {

        $this->setTable("<table class='table table-striped table-hover'>
                        <thead class='thead-inverse'>
                          <tr>");



        foreach ($columns as $columnName) {
            $this->setTable($this->getTable(). "<th>".$columnName."</th>" );
        }



        $this->setTable($this->getTable(). "</tr></thead><tbody>");


        for ($x = 0; $x != sizeof($values); $x++) {
            $this->setTable($this->getTable(). "<tr>");

            foreach ($values as $value) {
                $this->setTable($this->getTable(). "<td>".$value[$x] ."</td>");
                var_dump($value);
            }

            $this->setTable($this->getTable(). "</tr>");
        }

        $this->setTable($this->getTable(). "</tbody></table>");

        var_dump($this->getTable());
    }
```

I tried applying a order by on my select query. That will get rid of my problem on the array. Displaying the items right in the td is the issue. The td is created constantly until it got no values and starts a new array just like I showed with the picture. So is there anyway to fix the problem of displaying these values under the table header td?

Comment: Instead of making the "magic html generator" class, you should have used either [native templates](http://chadminick.com/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html) or something like [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/).

Comment: the problem is you used `fetch_array()` to get records which gave you numeric+associative array combo.Use `fetch_assoc()` so that second foreach will work perfectly.

Comment: Well I changed my fetchAll() to: fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC). This didn't do it. I can try changing it to FETCH_NUM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking to your array image,it seems you use `fetchAll()` to get records from the db.

`fetchAll()` provide numeric+associative array in combination. That's why your record coming like this:-

```
array(
     'userId'=>2,
     0=>2,
     'userEmail'=>'some value',
     1=>'same mail id'
);
```

Now you have only two theads `# and email`, but the second foreach provide you 4 `<td>` after each iteration, and hense table distorted.

***Solution:-*** You have to use `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM)` to resolve your issue and after that change your code like below:-

```
public function displayTable($columns, $values = 0){

    $this->setTable("<table class='table table-striped table-hover'><thead class='thead-inverse'><tr>");

    foreach ($columns as $columnName) {
        $this->setTable($this->getTable(). "<th>".$columnName."</th>" );
    }

    $this->setTable($this->getTable(). "</tr></thead><tbody>");


    for ($x = 0; $x != sizeof($values); $x++) {
        $this->setTable($this->getTable(). "<tr>");

        foreach ($values as $key=> $value) {
            $this->setTable($this->getTable(). "<td>".$value[$key] ."</td>");
        }
        $this->setTable($this->getTable(). "</tr>");
    }

    $this->setTable($this->getTable(). "</tbody></table>");

    var_dump($this->getTable());
}
```

Comment: Wel I tried the PDO::FETCH_ASSOC on my fetchAll. This didn't resolve the issue. In my second foreach I use $x to loop through the values of $value and using assoc gives me an error.

Comment: thanks. Still everything is going like this: first the th which is fine. Than the first tr as follows 1 2 and than the next one first email , second email. I specificilly want to display the id's under # and the emails under email

Comment: @RemcodeBaas  use the code i given in my edited answer.

Comment: @RemcodeBaas  that means `$values` have only single record. You need to pass `all records` array to the function.

Comment: So I have to pass the array I get from the database to the method. Because I already give the array with the result to the mehtod or you mean something very different

Comment: this is the array I pass to the method: array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(23) "remcodebaas@outlook.com" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(13) "remco@remco.o" } }.